# How to dismiss keyboard on button press in Xamarin Forms

Tags: keyboard, xamarin.forms

After much searching, I worked out a way to hide the keyboard on a button press in Xamarin Forms for iOS. So it's shared below.

If anyone can improve it, or share a solution for the Android side, that would be great.

Answer (score 25):

I found this useful:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/172077#Comment_172077

**Interface:**

```
public interface IKeyboardHelper
{
    void HideKeyboard();
}
```

**iOS:**

```
public class iOSKeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper
{
    public void HideKeyboard()
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(true);
    }
}
```

**Droid:**

```
public class DroidKeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper
{
    public void HideKeyboard()
    {
        var context = Forms.Context;
        var inputMethodManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
        if (inputMethodManager != null && context is Activity)
        {
            var activity = context as Activity;
            var token = activity.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
            inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, HideSoftInputFlags.None);

            activity.Window.DecorView.ClearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage in Xamarin Forms:**

```
DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardHelper>().HideKeyboard();
```

Comment: You need this line before the start of the namespace in each of your KeyboardHelper classes or the DependencyService will not find them.[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(xxxxxxKeyboardHelper))]

Comment: KUDOS to both F. Badili and JDibble.

Comment: Thanks mate... really worth the post

Comment: Thank u helped me out as well.

Comment: Dont work with android

Answer (score 12):

If the removing focus method is not working for you (and it wasn't working for me)  after a lot of searching I realized an easy way to force the keyboard to dismiss.

```
FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edittextname).Enabled = false;
FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edittextname).Enabled = true;
```

That's it. Just disable and enable it and it will close the keyboard.

Comment: `MyEntry.IsEnabled=false` works better than `MyEntry.UnFocus()`.

Comment: This worked better than `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(true);` and `View.UnFocus`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Super simple and still works on Xamarin.Forms 5

Comment: Taking Frank Hintsch' approach I used (in Maui) ((Entry)sender).isEnabled=false; ((Entry)sender).isEnabled=true;

Answer (score 9):

```
 view.Unfocus();
```

That's it.

Some people report this not working, but it's worked like gangbusters for me.

Comment: Unfocus() still getting the job down on Android & Xamarin Forms v.4.8.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an updated version of F. Badili's solution based on a deprecating change in Xamarin Forms 2.5. The only difference is how the Context is accessed in the Android class.

In the **Xamarin Forms** project:

```cs
public interface IKeyboardHelper
{
    void HideKeyboard();
}
```

In the **iOS** project:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ProjectName;
using ProjectName.iOS;
using UIKit;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(iOSKeyboardHelper))]
namespace ProjectName.iOS
{
    public class iOSKeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper
    {
        public void HideKeyboard()
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In the **Droid** Project:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ProjectName;
using ProjectName.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DroidKeyboardHelper))] 
namespace ProjectName.Droid
{
    public class DroidKeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper
    {
        public void HideKeyboard()
        {
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            var inputMethodManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            if (inputMethodManager != null && context is Activity)
            {
                var activity = context as Activity;
                var token = activity.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, HideSoftInputFlags.None);

                activity.Window.DecorView.ClearFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In **Xamarin Forms** page:

```cs
DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardHelper>().HideKeyboard();
```

Comment: **Android.App.Application.Context** didn't work for me. Only the **Forms.Context**. Because *context is Activity* getting false

Comment: For me, neither Forms.Context nor Application.Context worked. What did work was to use Plugin.CurrentActivity, with var context = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution to hide the virtual keyboard for the Android side.

I coded a IKeyboardInteractions interface which has a HideKeyboard() method. Then I declare a KeyboardInteractions class in MyProject.Droid which implements IKeyboardInteractions :

Common code :

```
public interface IKeyboardInteractions {
    void HideKeyboard();
}
```

MyProject.Droid code:

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (KeyboardInteractions))] namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class KeyboardInteractions : IKeyboardInteractions
    {
        public void HideKeyboard()
        {
            var inputMethodManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            if (inputMethodManager != null && Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context is Activity)
            {
                var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
                var token = activity.CurrentFocus == null ? null : activity.CurrentFocus.WindowToken;
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consuming method:

```
IKeyboardInteractions keyboardInteractions = DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardInteractions>();
keyboardInteractions.HideKeyboard ();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nicholas. Will be trying it out down the track.

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` is deprecated since XF 2.5. `Android.App.Application.Context` seems to be the wrong context. Which one do you use now?

Comment: @testing me too. **Android.App.Application.Context** didn't work for me. Only the **Forms.Context** working

Comment: For me, neither Forms.Context nor Application.Context worked. What did work was to use Plugin.CurrentActivity, with var context = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get F. Badili's solution for Android to work even with Kenan Casey's update on it. Further googling took me to [Dave's Tech Blog](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html) regarding the deprecation of `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context`. It says `Android.App.Application.Context` is not and can't be converted to `Activty` (at least in my case, refer to the blog post's comments for the explanation).

In the **Droid Project**:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DroidKeyboardHelper))] 
namespace ProjectName.Droid{
    public class DroidKeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper {
        static Context _context;

        public static void Init(Context context) => _context = context;

        public void HideKeyboard(){
            var inputMethodManager = _context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            if (inputMethodManager != null && _context is Activity) {
                var activity = _context as Activity;
                var token = activity.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, HideSoftInputFlags.None);

                activity.Window.DecorView.ClearFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the **Droid MainActivity.cs**:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    KeyboardHelper.Init(this);
    ...
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

> **NOTE**:
>
> > This will only work if your app only runs on a single activity. If in any case your app has multiple activity, please refer to [Dave's Tech Blog](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html) for a proper implementation for your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a name to the entry fields. For instance `Entryfield1` and `EntryField2` are the entries that showed the keyboard. Then override the Page Events with `OnDisappearing` like below:

```cs
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    Entryfield1.Unfocus();
    EntryField2.Unfocus();
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the shared/PCL project, add:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Views
{
    public class ButtonKeyboardHiding : Button {}
}
```

Use this class in place of Button in your forms.

In the iOS project, add:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MyApp.Views;
using MyApp.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer ( typeof (ButtonKeyboardHiding), typeof (ButtonKeyboardHidingRenderer ) ) ]

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class ButtonKeyboardHidingRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged ( ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e )
        {
            base.OnElementChanged  (e );

            if ( Control != null ) 
            {   
                Control.TouchUpInside += ( sender, el ) =>
                {
                    UIView ctl = Control;
                    while ( true )
                    {
                        ctl = ctl.Superview;
                        if ( ctl.Description.Contains ( "UIView" ) )
                            break;
                    }
                    ctl.EndEditing ( true );
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems ridiculous that you can't iterate through the views on a ListView. Thanks, for this idea.

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. And when I click the button a 2nd time (after keyboard closes), I'm getting an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Forms9Patch has a good working implementation.

So just use the whole library (https://github.com/baskren/Forms9Patch) or use their code from the Github repo ([KeyboardService.cs](https://github.com/baskren/Forms9Patch/blob/master/Forms9Patch/Forms9Patch/Services/KeyboardService.cs)).

Using it is quite easy then:

```cs
Forms9Patch.KeyboardService.Hide();
```

Available for Android, iOS and UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in code behind Xamarin Forms 4.8.  Subscribe to TextChanged event, i.e. Editor or Entry, then check the key in the code behind. As *Le Mot Juiced* answered, UnFocused() will close the keyboard. My example closes the keyboard after the enter key is pressed, but you can apply another key to the condition.

**XAML**

```
 <Editor TextChanged="Input_TextChanged"></Editor>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void Input_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        char key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue) ? ' ' : e.NewTextValue.Last();
        if (key == '\n')
        {
            var s = (Editor)sender;
            s.Text = e.OldTextValue ?? string.Empty;
            s.Unfocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well focus is lost, but it doesn't seem to make keyboard disappear? (I use this on a simple Entry element and adapted).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the keyboard was not closing for a TapGestureRecognizer for Android. To fix this I had to replace the Span with a button. Commented out code below is what was not working for me in terms of closing the keyboard. Keyboard was automatically closed on clicking the button in Android.

```
               <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>

            <!--
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Padding="20">
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="Login" TextColor="Blue">
                                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
                                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Span>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            -->
```

Answer (score 0):

UnFocus() worked for me, with some caveats.

I had two pages: EditPage had an Entry control, that, when focused, displayed the keyboard. ListPage had no Entry field.
When EditPage was displayed, and the Entry focused, the keyboard was displayed. If I now navigated to ListPage, the keyboard remained displayed.

To resolve, I tried these:

1.) In ListPage.OnAppearing() I added a call to Unfocus().

Silly, as there is nothing focused at this point, but if this is the way to hide the keyboard, was worth a try. Also, this page should be responsible for showing or hideing the keyboard, no matter where we caome from.

**Didn't work.**

2.) In EditPage.OnDisappearing(), I added Unfocus() like so:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    Unfocus();
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

**This works.**

Answer (score 0):

The best way i have found, API > 30 is to create an instance of MainActivity as a static resource:

```
internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
```

And then to reference it and hide the InsetsController that handles media entry:

```
MainActivity.Instance.Window.InsetsController.Hide(WindowInsets.Type.Ime());
```

This can be done using Dependency Service if using multi platform:

```
 IKeyboardInteractions kbi = DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardInteractions>();
            
 kbi.HideKeyboard();
```

The reverse can be done to show the keyboard at any time:

```
MainActivity.Instance.Window.InsetsController.Show(WindowInsets.Type.Ime());
```