# Hide keyboard when button is clicked in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms, I have a requirements that should hide the mobile keyboard when user click search button.

I am not sure yet how to do it in xamarin forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss keyboard on button press in Xamarin Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437362/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-on-button-press-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to do this, the most common are as follows:

```
  View.ResignFirstResponder();
```

OR

```
  View.EndEditing(true);
```