# How to dismiss a keyboard in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

What I'm looking for is a way to dismiss the keyboard while maintaining focus on the Entry field so an external keyboard can be used without giving up all that screen real estate.

I can't seem to implement the code in  [How to dismiss keyboard on button press in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437362/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-on-button-press-in-xamarin-forms) I'm calling it in the OnFocused of an Entry field.

```
Android.App.Application.Context as Activity;
```

is returning null Without the "as activity it works just fine, but I can't run

```
.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
```

on a Context.

This is what my code looks like.

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (KeyboardInteractions))] namespace namespace.Droid
{
    public class KeyboardInteractions : IKeyboardInteractions
    {
        public void HideKeyboard()
        {
        var activity = Android.App.Application.Context as Activity;
        var token = activity?.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
        var i = (InputMethodManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        if (token != null) {
            i.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try using the CurrentActivity plugin - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

Comment: Doesn't the Unfocus() method do exactly this?

Comment: I wanted it to remain focused.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin).

Once you have the plugin setup you can use it like this :

```
var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity;
```

In case of queries feel free to revert.