# Dismiss keyboard when scrolling sfListView

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

What the best way (preferably cross-platform) to dismiss keyboard when user starts scrolling sfListView in Xamarin project for IOS and Android? If no cross-platform solution exists - would be glad to hear solutions for both IOS and Android separately. Thank you in advance

Comment: Did your solve your problem or tried my solution?

Comment: Yes, your solution worked. Marked it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking into [documention](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/scrolling#identifying-scroll-state-changes) of sfListView, you can find `the Identifying scroll state changes` part, so you can dismiss keyboard in this event:

```
listView.ScrollStateChanged += ListView_ScrollStateChanged;

private void ListView_ScrollStateChanged(object sender, ScrollStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollState != ScrollState.Idle)
    {
        //dismiss keyboard
        DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardHelper>().HideKeyboard();
    }
}
```

To dismiss the keyboard, you have to use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/):

You can use the code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437362/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-on-button-press-in-xamarin-forms).

**Note**: Remember to add this line before the start of the namespace in each of your KeyboardHelper classes or the DependencyService will not find them.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(xxxxxxKeyboardHelper))]
```