# Maui Soft Keyboard Disable for Entry

Tags: maui

I know there is a bug for the soft keyboard hiding and I have read the work arounds, but I just curious if anyone has found a solid solution that allow the keyboard to not appear at all without effect the runtime? Im trying to build a barcode scanner app but the soft keyboard keeps appearing when focusing on the entry or when the scanner is inputting the data. I would like it to work on both android and iOS. =(

Comment: What do you need an Entry for at all if you don't want to use the keyboard?

Comment: The device we are planning on using has a built in scanner and needs to have a entry to input the data (Keystroke) and I was going to use on text change to trigger the submission once it reaches the suffix of the data input.

Comment: *" I have read the work arounds"* Unless improved, this question will probably get closed as a duplicate or as too vague. Add links to the one(s) you tried, and show the **exact code** of your implementation.

Comment: Did the answer in the thread ["Need a way to hide soft keyboard in MAUI's Editor / Entry fields"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199602/need-a-way-to-hide-soft-keyboard-in-mauis-editor-entry-fields) help you?

Answer (score 0):

In Maui, you can use Handler to achieve the effect you want on the iOS and Android platforms respectively. I did a simple test and the soft keyboard will not pop up on both platforms and the keyboard input can be performed normally.
You can refer to this:

Xaml:

```
<Entry Text="111"/>
```

.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModifyEntry();

    }

    void ModifyEntry()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.EditorAction += (s, e) =>
            {
                handler.PlatformView.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
            };

#elif IOS

            handler.PlatformView.EditingDidBegin += (s, e) =>
            {
                handler.PlatformView.InputView=new UIKit.UIView();
                
            };
#endif
        });
    }
```

Hope it can help you. For more usage of Handler, you can refer to the document: [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0)