# Hide keyboard after Focus event

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

There is an Entry field `ScannedValue` in my Maui application that I want to use for scanning barcodes with a Bluetooth scanner. I'm targeting Android and iOS platform.
The Entry needs to be focused so that the scanner transfers the barcode into that field. However, every time the field gets focused the keyboard automatically opens and I don't want that.
The whole page is basically a (UraniumUI) TabView which fires an event as soon as the selected tab changes. If the new tab is the one responsible for using the bluetooth scanner, the focus should get set on the entry field.

```
private void TabView_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, UraniumUI.Material.Controls.TabItem e) {

if (e == null)
    return;

if (e.Title.Equals(AppResources.UseBarcodeScanner))
{
    SetFocus();
}
}
```

SetFocus looks like this:

```
private void SetFocus() {
this.ScannedValue.Focus();

this.ScannedValue.IsEnabled = false;
this.ScannedValue.IsEnabled = true; 
}
```

The field gets focused correctly, but the keyboard does not get closed. As you can see I tried to set `IsEnabled`, but that does not work. I also tried to create an Interface and a KeyboardHelper class as shown in the following question: [Need a way to hide soft keyboard in MAUI's Editor / Entry fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199602/need-a-way-to-hide-soft-keyboard-in-mauis-editor-entry-fields)

I also tried to use the following methods:

```
await ScannedValue.HideSoftInputAsync(default);
await ScannedValue.HideKeyboardAsync();
await KeyboardExtensions.HideKeyboardAsync(ScannedValue);
```

But nothing works. What am I missing here?

Comment: So, if you're using a bluetooth scanner (and not using the device's own camera to scan the barcode) would it be accurate to infer that this is just for WinUI? Or are there other reasons for using the external scanner? (This might have a bearing on how an answer might go from a usability standpoint).

Comment: Which platform you are targeting?

Comment: I would recommend, that you read the Android specification about [Handle keyboard input](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I'm targeting Android and iOS. Edited the question.

Comment: Awww yes, two years complains that MAUI does not open keyboard on focus, and now two more that it does. Because the "Show soft input on focus" was too hard to implement in 8.0. It is "planned" for 9.0 thou. 9 more months to go. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @IV. no, this is for Android and iOS. The reason for using a bluetooth scanner is, that the app will be used by some customers of mine, who insist to scan their codes with a mobile scanner and not with the device's camera. That's unfortunately not my decision to make.

Comment: Got it! One more question. Is the reason for using an `Entry` field to allow the user to edit or create barcodes manually?

Comment: I'll go ahead and post what I was thinking as a possibility, but if the barcode field needs to be editable then some adjustments would need to be made but not major.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is just a perspective, one option. The focus issue can be sidestepped entirely if one chooses to treat a scan more like an *activity* style flow. So if there's a barcode field to fill, in this model it would be represented by a label with a tap gesture recognizer. So, *cheat to win* mentality there is no focus issue in to begin with. Tapping the label brings up an overlay.

---

With the option of using the device's camera it might be something like this:

[image: scanning with camera]

---

If you're using the external bluetooth scanner, the flow might be something more like this:

[image: scanning with external]

---

In either case, the event that occurs when the scan completes causes the result to be copied onto the "box".

---

###### Main Page

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        barcodeScanner.Options = new ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeReaderOptions
        {
            Formats = 
                ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.UpcA | 
                ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.UpcE |
                ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.Code128 |
                ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.QrCode,
            TryHarder = true,
        };
        barcodeScanner.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    new BarcodeScannerBindingContext BindingContext => (BarcodeScannerBindingContext)base.BindingContext;
    private void OnBarcodeDetected(object sender, ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext.BarcodeLabelText = $"{e.Results.FirstOrDefault()?.Value}";
        BindingContext.IsDetectingInternal = false;
        Vibration.Vibrate();
    }
}
```

---

###### View Model

```
class BarcodeScannerBindingContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BarcodeScannerBindingContext()
    {
        ScanCommand = new Command(OnScan);
        CancelCommand = new Command(OnCancel);
    }
    public ICommand ScanCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnScan(object o)
    {
        if(UseExternal)
        {
            IsDetectingExternal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsDetectingInternal = true;
        }
    }
    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnCancel(object o)
    {
        IsDetectingInternal = IsDetectingExternal = false;
    }
    public bool IsDetecting
    {
        get => _isDetecting;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isDetecting, value))
            {
                _isDetecting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isDetecting = false;

    public bool UseExternal
    {
        get => _useExternal;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_useExternal, value))
            {
                _useExternal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _useExternal = default;


    public bool IsDetectingInternal
    {
        get => _isDetectingInternal;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isDetectingInternal, value))
            {
                _isDetectingInternal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            IsDetecting = value;
        }
    }
    bool _isDetectingInternal = default;

    public bool IsDetectingExternal
    {
        get => _isDetectingExternal;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isDetectingExternal, value))
            {
                _isDetectingExternal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            IsDetecting = value;
        }
    }
    bool _isDetectingExternal = default;

    public string BarcodeLabelText
    {
        get => _barcodeLabelText;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_barcodeLabelText, value))
            {
                _barcodeLabelText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _barcodeLabelText = "|";

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string? propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

###### Xaml

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"             
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
    xmlns:xzing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.MAUI.Controls"             
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BarcodeScanner"             
    x:Class="BarcodeScanner.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:BarcodeScannerBindingContext />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:InvertBoolConverter x:Key="InvertBoolConverter"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Padding="30,0"
                Spacing="25">
                <Image
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    HeightRequest="185"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />
                <Label
                    Text="Barcode Scanner"
                    Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />
                <Label
                    Text="{Binding BarcodeLabelText}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    BackgroundColor="Azure"
                    Padding="2,1">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ScanCommand}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
                <Grid
                    ColumnDefinitions="*,2*"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <CheckBox 
                        IsChecked="{Binding UseExternal}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        Text="Use Bluetooth"/>
                </Grid>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Grid
            IsVisible="{Binding IsDetectingInternal}">
            <xzing:CameraBarcodeReaderView
                x:Name="barcodeScanner"
                VerticalOptions="Fill"
                BarcodesDetected="OnBarcodeDetected"
                IsDetecting="{Binding IsDetectingInternal}">
            </xzing:CameraBarcodeReaderView>
            <Grid
                RowDefinitions="*,100,*">
                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                    Opacity="0.75"
                    Margin="0"
                    CornerRadius="0"/>
                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    Margin="0"
                    Opacity="0.75" />
                <!--Do not move! We need this zorder-->
                <Button
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Text="Cancel"
                    Margin="0,20"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
            IsVisible="{Binding IsDetectingExternal}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Frame
                Opacity="0.8"
                BackgroundColor="#222222">
            </Frame>
            <ActivityIndicator
                HeightRequest="80"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                IsRunning="True"
                Margin="0,25"
                Color="White"/>
            <Label
                Grid.Row="2"
                Text="Waiting for Scan..."
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,20"
                HeightRequest="40"
                WidthRequest="200"
                TextColor="White"
                FontAttributes="Italic"
                FontSize="Medium"/>
            <Button
                Grid.Row="2"
                Text="Cancel"
                Margin="0,20"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                HeightRequest="40"
                WidthRequest="200"
                Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I like the creativity of this solution.

Comment: That is indeed a creative and clever approach to the problem. Did you test if the OnBarcodeDetected event fires when scanning with a bluetooth scanner? If I understand correctly, the Zxing.Net.Maui library only handles barcode detection with the built-in camera.

Comment: It's true what you say about ZXing. I thought it sounded like you had the bluetooth part working? So I tried to deal with the "problem at hand" about the focus. If you have a GitHub repo for your project I could help get it hooked in because I'm doing this kind of thing in my own app and there is some "enlightened self-interest" involved in answering. Here's my [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/BarcodeScanner.git) so far, where I took a Xamarin barcode scan that's been working great and tried just now to port it to MAUI. You'll notice in the comments there's a few things to still work out.

Comment: No, my idea was to focus the entry field, wait for the scanner to fill it with text and then handle the 'TextChanged' event from the entry. This way would also be possible with your 2nd approach. Like you could show the "Waiting for scan" popup, focus the entry, then wait for the field to get filled with text and then handle the text.
[Here](https://github.com/fryndorfer/BarcodeScanner/tree/main)'s my repo. The scanning takes place in **Views\BulkScan** and **ViewModels\BulkScanViewModel**.  I develop in the MVVM pattern and I'm using the Community Toolkit.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to share it with you. Sent the invitation.

Comment: yes of course, feel free to open issues :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a .cs file:

   internal class CustomEntry : Entry{}
2. Use AppendToMapping for your EntryHandler

   ```
        EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is CustomEntry)
            {
                handler.PlatformView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
            }
        });
   ```
3. Add it to your XAML:

   < controls:CustomEntry/>

This is not the best solution.

First, you will need to add code for IOS, because this is Android only.
Second, notice how this is extending a class. If you want to change such properties on the go, you should do quite some work.
Third, sometimes it is up the device itself. I have a professional device that is smart enough to not open its soft keyboard on numeric fields, and let you use the hardware keys... unless you tap it.

There are other ways to approach this problem, this is just an idea.