# How to stop the operation of CameraBarcodeReaderView from ZXing.Net.Maui library?

Tags: c#, maui, zxing.net, zxing.net.mobile

I implemented un `CameraBarcodeReaderView` of `ZXing.Net.Maui` for reader codes QR, for this i did:

I have two ContentPage's, one its my principal (MainPage) view and other second contentpage content the `CameraBarcodeReaderView` component (SecondPage). The Second page it's called through of a button from MainPage.

```
// Called SecondPage from button of MainPage
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SecondPage(this));
}
```

When the `CameraBarcodeReaderView` detected a valid Code QR, returning the value of code QR to MainPage and returning to MainPage the focus of app.

```
    protected void BarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (detected==0)
        { 
            detected = 1;
            ReturnMainPage(e.Results[0].Value);
        }
         
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returning to MainPage the code detected from camara
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">Code detected from camara</param>
    public async void ReturnMainPage(string code)
    {
        pather_clients.code = code;                      
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(MainPage);
    }
```

But the problem is that the `CameraBarcodeReaderView` component stays active and continuous reading QR Codes and I can't stop it.

How do I stop this `CameraBarcodeReaderView` component?
or
How do I Remove/Delete/Disponse the SecondPage?
or
Does anyone have a better way to implement the  `CameraBarcodeReaderView` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post states that the `CameraBarcodeReaderView` "stays active" and performs "continuous reading". There are two booleans that you can use to idle it, and the one I would personally use  is `IsDetecting`, shown here with a binding to the view model (and there is also `IsEnabled`).

```
<Grid
    IsVisible="{Binding IsDetectingInternal}">
    <xzing:CameraBarcodeReaderView
        x:Name="barcodeScanner"
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        BarcodesDetected="OnBarcodeDetected"
        IsDetecting="{Binding IsDetecting}">
        ...
```

For a working example of this, including a GitHub code repo, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78201261/5438626) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78199431/5438626) because it does the very thing you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below in the constructor of the ContentPage to release the camera resource:

```
 Unloaded += (sender, e) => { cameraBarcodeReaderView.Handler.DisconnectHandler(); };
```

Add don't forget to add the `x:Name` of the control to the XAML page like below:

```
<zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="cameraBarcodeReaderView" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```